# My Arduino keeps telling me the button is being pushed

Tags: arduino-mega, button

My code is simple simple for the button.

There is no reason why this shouldn't work... I think. I honestly have no clue what's wrong.

Output:

[image: Output]

Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Bounce2.h>

#define SS_PIN 53
#define RST_PIN 5
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

int led = 13;
int led2 = 12;

Bounce debouncer1 = Bounce(); 

// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

int buzzer = 10;

Servo LockServo;

int ServoPos = 0;

void setup() 
{
  debouncer1.attach(buttonPin);
  debouncer1.interval(5); // interval in ms

  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // Push Button as INPUT wiith pullup
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  LockServo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop()
{
  debouncer1.update();
  buttonState = debouncer1.read();
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Button Pushed");
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    ServoPos = 0;
    LockServo.write(ServoPos);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    ServoPos = 180;
    LockServo.write(ServoPos);
  }

  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "20 96 2E A5") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    ServoPos = 0;
    LockServo.write(ServoPos);
    tone(buzzer, 20000);
    delay(500);
    noTone(buzzer);

    tone(buzzer, 15000);
    delay(500);
    noTone(buzzer);
    delay(15);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(3000);
    ServoPos = 180;
    LockServo.write(ServoPos);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    tone(buzzer, 10000);
    delay(500);
    noTone(buzzer);

    tone(buzzer, 30000);
    delay(500);
    noTone(buzzer);
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    noTone(buzzer);
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (buttonState == HIGH) {` means the button is NOT pressed when using `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);`

Comment: you are asking about a pushbutton problem, yet your code has a bunch of stuff for servos and MFRC522 .... please reduce the program to the code necessary to demonstrate the issue with the pushbutton

Answer (score 3):

When using a pull-up mode on an input pin, that means that when nothing is connected, the pin floats up to `HIGH`. The connected button should have one side connected to your input pin, and the other to `GND`, so that when you press the button, the input pin is pulled to `GND` (that is, `LOW`).

So your comparison to trigger on a button press should be `if (buttonState == LOW)`